# Populating entity properties after seeding entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have the following class, where NextNode points to another instance of the Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? NextNodeId { get; set; }
    public Node? NextNode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Since I can't reference a node that doesn't yet exist in the `NextNode` property, is it possible to seed the database in two steps?

First create, the nodes, and then second, populate the `NextNode` property?

Comment: Since this is seeding I assume that Id's are not database generated, is it correct? Also what are you using for seeding? `HasData`?

Comment: Correct.  I was going to generate the Ids for seeding.  I'm currently using `HasData`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will generate the Ids you can simply fill in the `NextNodeId`'s without filling `NextNode` for `HasData`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasData(new List<Node>
    {
        new Node
        {
            Id = 1,
            NextNodeId = 2
        },
        new Node
        {
            Id = 2
        }
    });
```

If you decide to create custom seeding code with `Add(Range)` + `SaveChanges(Async)` then you can just create corresponding hierarchy and add it, EF should be able to handle this:

```cs
ctx.Nodes.AddRange(new Node
{
    Id = 1, // skip ids if they are database generated
    NextNode = new Node
    {
        Id = 2 // skip ids if they are database generated
    }
});
ctx.SaveChanges();
```